# How write two main function in neighbouring actors?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, program-entry-point, intellij-13

I am experimenting with akka, I have written two dummy actors with main function in them:

**HelloActor**

```
package akkaSample.severalSystems

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}

class HelloActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "mew" => println("I said mew")
    case "hello" => println("hello back at you")
    case "shutdown" => context.stop(self)
    case _       => println("huh?")
  }
}
object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  println("started")
}
```

**OtherActor**

```
package akkaSample.severalSystems

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}

class OtherActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "mew" => println("I said mew")
    case _       => println("huh?")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  println("started")
}
```

I am trying to run main function from intellij idea (both from OtherActor and HelloActor) and get compilation error:

```
Error:(12, 8) Main is already defined as object Main
object Main extends App {
       ^
```

Why I get it? Main functions are placed in different files! How to write 2 main funcitons in scala/akka and run them from neighbouring actors?

Also with to empty scala classes which do not extends actor main function work, here is the code:

**class One**

```
package akkaSample.mainError

class One {

}
object Main extends App {
  println("Hi!")
}
```

**class Two**

```
package akkaSample.mainError

class Two {

}

object Main extends App {
  println("Hi!")
}
```

No compilation error.

**P.S.** It is just for experimenting I do not plan to put code with 2 main functions in production.

Comment: I compiled code with sbt and I received the same error, with raw scalac too. `scalac src/main/scala/akkaSample/mainError/One.scala  src/main/scala/akkaSample/mainError/Two.scala`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined an object with the same name twice. There is no way for the compiler to distinguish between the two.

An object that extends `App` does not need to be called `Main`. You can call one `HelloActorMain` and other `OtherActorMain`. In that case sbt will let you choose which main class to run.

Comment: But why two empty classes which do not extends Actor trait do not generate compile-time error? (see classes `one` and `two` in the question)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error says it all: you are trying to define an object called akkaSample.severalSystems.Main, but there is already an object with the same name which exists. That's not possible, because the compiler will need to generate a JVM class with the same name for both (akkaSample.severalSystems.Main$), so they couldn't be loaded at the same time; besides, they would have to be written in files with the same name (Main$.class) and in the same directory.

I'm more curious as to why your second example doesn't generate an error - but it certainly has to do with your two objects not just having identical names, but being exactly identical.